# Создание virtualenv на флешке

Tags: python, virtualenv, django

Как правильно сделать виртуальное окружение на флешке? Даже под sudo говорит

```
wolf@wolf-pc:/media/C47D-5F53$ sudo virtualenv django
New python executable in django/bin/python
ERROR: The executable django/bin/python could not be run: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Навскидку — монтируйте без `noexec`.

`cat /proc/mounts | grep -F /media/C47D-5F53`

`sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/C47D-5F53`

Comment: Не помогает. Опять пишет о недостаточности прав

Comment: Чтобы не плутать в догадках... Что первая команда (которая «`cat ... | grep ...`») выдает?

Еще у FAT/NTFS нет POSIX-прав и, соответственно, executable bit. Как правило, его система ставит на все файлы, но иногда наоборот. Определяется это, если я правильно помню, параметрами `umask` и `fmask`. Соответственно, можно попробовать что-то в духе `mount -o remount,umask=000 /media/C47D-5F53`.

Comment: wolf@wolf-pc:/media/1A2C-5AB1$ cat /proc/mounts | grep -F /media/1A2C-5AB1
/dev/sdb1 /media/1A2C-5AB1 vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro 0 0

Comment: virtualenv использует символические ссылки на версию python, пакеты и иные инструменты. Навскидку у вас просто fat32 на флешке, которая символические ссылки попросту не поддерживает. Попробуйте форматирвать в ntfs или ext. Но скорее всего следующая проблема, с которой вы столкнётесь будет неработоспособность на других машинах (т.к. симлинки будут указывать в никуда).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте файловую систему ext4. Отформатируйте вашу флешку через любой Linux:

для начала выгрузите ее:

```
umount /dev/sdb1
```

далее, форматируем:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```